# Сумма значений поля модели всех обьектов

Tags: python, django

Есть модель

```
class tt(models.Model):
    ...
    tt_like = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)
    ...
```

Я вывожу в шаблон кол-во всех объектов:

```
ololo = tt.objects.all().count()
```

А теперь хочу вывести результат суммы поля `tt_like` со всех объектов.
Т.е. есть у меня 7 обектов модели `tt`, у каждого свое поле `tt_like` с разными значениями, нужно их суммировать.

Нужно запускать в цикл или есть функция для подсчета? Во всяком случае никак не могу это правильно написать...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вы можете использовать метод `aggregate` объекта queryset:

```
>>> from django.db.models Sum
>>> tt.objects.aggregate(total_likes=Sum('tt_like'))
{'total_likes': 0.4470664529184653}
```

[Документация по функциям агрегации](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/)